# Backend interprocess custom events in PHP

Tags: php, events, ipc, native

I need to implement an inter-process event mechanism in PHP, with multiple event emitters and multiple event listeners. For example, a PHP script running in cron could detect a new incoming phone call and trigger a custom event, named `MY_EVENT_INCOMMING_CALL`. Any other PHP CLI/Apache scripts running in the same time (waiting for an event, in loop) would be notified that that event has triggered and do some work. For example, a Server Sent Event could be sent to the internet browsers currently connected and display a popup notification that an incoming call has arrived. One more thing: a listening script should get only the events triggered AFTER the script started listening, older events should not be processed.

One implementation is using a SQL table holding the events, with some scripts inserting events, other pooling for new events (based on a event time-stamp), and an event garbage collector script that deletes old events.

I'm not interested in third party tools like RabbitMQ.

Is there any native PHP mechanism/library for this kind of situation?

UPDATE: I still haven't found a native implementation and ended using sockets; I posted the implementation here: https://github.com/xprt64/events

Comment: Depends what you want to do with it e.g. how many users? You can use any information sharing method like Sessions, files, databases and sockets. It just depends on the situation.

Comment: Why don't you want to use 3rd party? *curious*

Comment: For 1000+ users; 1:session is not OK, because CLI script don't have session;2: Sockets could be a solution but it is too complicated; I tried using one UDP socket for concurent writes but only one process can read, as the data is/must-be removed from the socket after read operation; thus one socket must be used for write and multiple sockets for read and an central event manager would copy data from the write socket to the read sockets (one read socket for each event listeners). 3:I already stated DB as a solution but is not native event mechanism; 4: files? how exactly?

Comment: @Michael: I'm also curios if a native implementation exists.I will use 3rd party if no native implementation exists. I want_to/try_to do this in PHP, not in something else.